# וַיהוָה נָתַן אֶת־חֵן הָעָם בְּעֵינֵי מִצְרַיִם (Exo. 12:36): How did Adonai give "favor" (חֵן)?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, bo

It says that Adonai gave the people of Israel "favor" in the eyes of the Egyptians. How is it that God caused the Egyptians to look upon the Israelites favorably? It seems to me that He had to work upon their heart or something. You know...the text implies a change of disposition. How did God affect that change?

Answer (score 1):

[Ibn Ezra to Shemos 3:21](http://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Shemot/3.21#e0n7) implies that it was done via miracle, as he calls it a "Davar Peleh".  This is according to his view that the Egyptians begged the Jews to please take their possessions (without even being asked).

Ralbag there (same link as Ibn Ezra) suggests that Hashem made the Egyptians feel naturally guilty that they had not paid the Jews for their work, and that they should at least lend them nice things for their short vacation.